# Web Scraping Prices with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I was following an online tutorial at the following webpage, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCuPv3tf2Hg&list=PLRzwgpycm-Fio7EyivRKOBN4D3tfQ_rpu&index=1. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I have tried the code in both Visual Studio and Jupyter notebooks to no avail.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

bURL = 'https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/c/540/taiwanese-whisky'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/c/540/taiwanese-whisky')

soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

productlist = soup.find_all('div', class_='item')
productlinks = []

for item in productlist:
    for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
        print(link['href'])
```

Comment: What is your question? What went wrong? Also please post your code properly using the `{}` button on the toolbar.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and see what requests.get returns. Dump the html in a file and open it.

Comment: @Selcuk, The individual in the video pulls up a long list of information based upon the the small block of code I put up above. Whenever I run the code in visual studio, a python.exe window pops up with no information at all. It literally just says push any key to continue. I have never done web scraping before and this project is the first I have ever used Python on. I have basic understanding of C++, Verilog, and Machine Code. The question is, what am I doing wrong if that person in the video is able to pull up the data based upon the above code. Also, thank you for the tip about code.

Comment: @mr_mooo_cow, could you give a link or an example for what you mean?  I am very new to attempting to use code for something other than basic electronics and performing calculations. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The structure of that website has changed since the video was posted.

I've fixed your code below:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

bURL = 'https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/c/540/taiwanese-whisky'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'} 

r = requests.get(bURL, headers=headers)

soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')

for x in soup.find_all('li', {'class':'product-grid__item'}):
    link = x.find('a')
    print(x.text, 'https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com'+link['href'])
```

Comment: thank you for your time and response! Why did you have to make those changes to the code? Where could I look to understand those changes? What IDE would you suggest using this in? I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I still wasn't able to pull that information with the above code. I am very new to using python and attempting to accomplish web scraping. Again thank you

Comment: I had to change the code because the website layout was different from what your code was looking for. If you got to that whisky site url in chrome and you right click on a whisky then click "inspect" you will see the html for the we page. This is what Beautiful Soup helps us parse. Each whisky is in an "li" tag (an ordered list, which makes sense because there are lots of whiskies in a list) they all have the class identifier of "product-grid__item" so we can find them by looking for those. That's what the for loop is doing "find_all" of them and loop through each one. I code in vs code

Comment: I finally got it working correctly. Thank you!!